# Как можно задать проверку двух элементов?

Tags: jquery, html

Имеется html разметка. Для наглядности покрасил блоки, чтобы правильней объяснить свой вопрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот jquery код:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    if($('div').is('[class*=icon-my]')){
     $('div.icon_block').removeClass('icon_block').addClass('icon_block_my_big').css("background-color","yellow");
    }

    });
```

Но при таком коде срабатывает условие для всех блоков (зеленых, оранжевый).
Вопрос: как можно переделать мой код, чтобы условие срабатывало только на зеленые блоки?

Comment: Сделайте демо на jsfiddle с разметкой.

Comment: Разделите ul или li еще на классы "green" и "orange" и работайте с ними.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div[class*=icon-my]')
    .closest('ul')
    .find('.icon_block')
    .removeClass('icon_block')
    .addClass('icon_block_my_big')
    .css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="icon_block">1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="icon icon-my-05">2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="icon_block">3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="icon icon-my-06">4</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="icon_block">1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="icon icon-iba">2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: VenZell, спасибо вам большое, все работает. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: @Максим Герасимов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).